# RoR; Object expected got string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I found several topics related , but couldn't figure out how to solve this problem,

This is my code

```
 <%= f.label :projeto %><br>

 <%= f.collection_select :projeto, Projeto.order(:id), :id, :name, include_blank: true %>

model => task belongs_to projeto and projeto has_many tasks
```

Full Error:

```
ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch at /tasks/1

Projeto(#69996814678740) expected, got String(#69996762580840)
```

Database is set to t.references.

Task_controller

```
def update
  respond_to do |format|
    if @task.update(task_params)
      format.html { redirect_to @task, notice: 'Task was successfully updated.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @task }
    else
      format.html { render :edit }
      format.json { render json: @task.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end

def task_params
  params.require(:task).permit(:seq, :descr, :seqpai, :typo, :hour, :projeto)
end


Started PATCH "/tasks/1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-06-18 14:30:23 -0300
Processing by TasksController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"Is7YTC0v5OONEEsIgOvmI+CEuVYG/WsoKWzskGippD2eOwthKVHb2dI+S19GkkI9aU0IwTrzwERlLq2ybWbGxw==", "task"=>{"seq"=>"0", "descr"=>"Projeto", "seqpai"=>"", "typo"=>"Analitica", "hour"=>"12", "projeto"=>"1"}, "commit"=>"Update Task", "id"=>"1"}
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  Task Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "tasks".* FROM "tasks" WHERE "tasks"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
   (0.2ms)  begin transaction
   (0.1ms)  rollback transaction
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 25ms (ActiveRecord: 0.8ms)
```

Comment: Are you sure the error is in the view code you posted? Please post the entire stack trace.

Comment: No, i'm not sure, sorry.

Comment: Please post the entire error stacktrace.

Comment: Well, it says this line " if @task.update(task_params)" in the task_controller

Comment: Here we go, it's in the controller, not in the view. Again, post the entire stacktrace and all the relevant controller code.

Comment: Application Frames All Frames

    block in TasksController#update
    app/controllers/tasks_controller.rb, line 49
    TasksController#update
    app/controllers/tasks_controller.rb, line 48
)

Answer (score 0):

Normally this is caused by assigning a string to something expecting a model association. For example:

```
# Not allowed, `project=` expects a Project model
@task.project = params[:project_id]

# Converts parameter into model, but may throw exception
@task.project = Project.find(params[:project_id])

# Direct assignment, requires validation on model level
@task.project_id = params[:project_id]
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed the View for  
    <%= f.label :projeto_id %>

and permited in controller projeto_id

Then worked Fine,

Thanks everyone for the hint.